# VBA-Autofill formula to left and down

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

I need VBA code to auto fill the ranges. Cell `H3` will have the default formula as shown.It shall be auto filled based on values available in column `G to AB1`. 
eg: In the pic  there is an operator `d` in `G6` and  the code `W03` in `L2`. So the autofill shall inlcude `H3 to L6`. However,these ranges may vary till `G80 to AB1`.

Comment: Manually autofill the cells you want while recording a macro and see what that does and try to adapt the code that generates for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

See how this works.

```
Sub Frmla()
    Dim rws As Long, rng As Range
    rws = Cells(rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("H2:L" & rws)
    rng.Formula = "=MyFormula"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Davesexcel .However, the range will vary till AB1.So  Set rng = Range("H2:L" & rws)